# CSS coding (ID & Class)

Tags: html, css

Let suppose i have two html pages p1 & p2 and it uses different layouts l1 & l2 respectively. I have to design the two different layouts and i only want to use common ID names. I just tried to let you understand that what i have in my mind, pls conisder js fn too (id does matter when we use js).

```
  commonPage.css
    p1 > l1 > #right { width:25%; height:25% .... }
            > #left  { width:25%; height:25% .... }  

    p2 > l2 > #right { width:30%; height:35% .... }
            > #left  { width:30%; height:35% .... }
```

follwing are html pages :

```
 p1.html
  <html> <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="commonPage.css" type="text/css"/>
   </head> <body>  
   <div id = "l1.right"></div>        <div id= "l1.left"></div>   </body></html>

 p2.html
  <html> <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="commonPage.css" type="text/css"/>
   </head> <body>
     <div id = "l2.right"></div>    <div id= "l2.left"></div>   </body></html>
```

@***Edit My Question is : how to write same Id names for many html tags with different properties and it should not affect to each other.***

Comment: how to write same Id names for many html tags with different properties  OR   am i right the way i have written ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't identify HTML elements in a page by the page's file name, so you have to either put the unique styles in `style` tags in each page, or use IDs/classes for each page.

In p1.html, give your `body` element an ID of `p1`, name it `p2` in p2.html, name both of your `div`s `right` and `left` respectively, so your HTML looks like this (showing only `body` contents):

p1.html

```
<body id="p1">
  <div id="right"></div> 
  <div id="left"></div>
</body>
```

p2.html

```
<body id="p2">
  <div id="right"></div> 
  <div id="left"></div>
</body>
```

Then use these selectors:

```
#p1 > #right 
#p1 > #left 
#p2 > #right 
#p2 > #left
```

Comment: great ! this is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Class names might fit better

```
//.... Html
<div class='left1' id='data'>
    <div class='left2' id='info'>
        your code goes here
    </div>
more code goes here
</div>
```

Css

```
.left1
{
/*css code here*/
}
.left2
{
/*css code here*/
}
```

Comment: from seeing your question, I think classes are the way to go. (i started my answer before you added your question)

Comment: For the javascript, use jquery. Lets you use class, id, name, and tag really easily

Comment: yes, i know class can be use for same properties but each div has different properties that's why i have to write either separate class or ID for each one, but i want to use some common name. let suppose if i have 100 div with different properties so i need 100 id/class name, but i want to use some common names with different properties.

Comment: @user: You need to have 100 IDs or classes no matter what. You can't identify HTML elements in a page by the page's file name.

Comment: I have created a php page that uses class with jquery to hide all divs then use a unque id to expanded the div I want to see.